# What does renderer.setSize really do?

Tags: three.js, screen, resolution, renderer

I am trying to learn how adapting things to different screen resolutions works in three.js.

Unfortunately, I have not found anywhere a good and understandable explanation about what the metod "renderer.setSize();" really does. I have revised the official documentation, but the details given are very brief.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what additional information would you like to have from [`Renderer.setSize()` in the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setSize)?

Answer (score 1):

You can freely look at the source: [`WebGLRenderer`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js)

So, `setSize` mostly configures the `canvas` size attributes and style, then calls `setViewport`...

In `setViewport` we see it set a `Vector4` with the width/height info. It also goes on to configure the viewport on the state, which takes us into [`WebGLState`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLState.js)...

In the `WebGLState.viewport` function, it also sets `Vector4` values, but it also calls:

```js
gl.viewport( viewport.x, viewport.y, viewport.z, viewport.w );
```

This is important, because it configures the viewport for the GL context.

[MDN: `WebGLRenderingContext.viewport`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/viewport)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer !. I really needed to know the sequence of steps that that method carries out in order to understand where it could fit best in my code. So I guess what it basically does is a sort of canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight*pixelRatio; etc, right?. (that is, it modifies the drawing buffer). Also, in what way does it modify the viewport, like, what parameters does it send to gl.viewport?. Thank you !

Comment: And what is the difference between the three.js "camera" and the viewport?. isn't modifying the camera the same as modifying the viewport and viceversa?. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeLlombart Again, I recommend you look at the code so see what is sent to GL. A "camera," to put it simply, is an convenience interface to manipulating the view matrix and projection matrix. Discussing how it does this is well beyond the scope of this question/answer, so I recommend you ask separate questions, and continue to research 3D graphics and the three.js code.